# What Ubuntu-compatible software is available to remove shaking from a video?

Tags: video, video-editor

I've got some some home movies that look great, but my video camera doesn't have one of those fancy new stabilizers. Is there extant end-user software (preferably FLOSS) I could use to removing the shaking?

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer, but YouTube offer some video editing capabilities that include vibration reduction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [Transcode](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/transcode)

*[Transcode](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/transcode) is no longer maintained and was removed from Ubuntu releases 18.04 and newer. You may [still be able to run it](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transcode) but functions may be limited or buggy.*

You can deshake a video with the use of an external stabilizer plugin available here

- [Transcode video stabilization plugin](http://public.hronopik.de/vid.stab/)

or from the Ubuntu multiverse repository in 18.04 or older:

```
sudo apt install transcode
```

After installation of the plugin you can stabilize a video with the following command:

```
transcode -J stabilize -i inmovie -y null,null -o dummy
```

This will give you an output file with definitions for transforms that will have to be performed as a second step (here using default options):

```
transcode -J transform -i inmovie -y xvid,null -o outmovie
```

For further details and many additional options also see:

- [Stabilizer Plugin Wiki](http://public.hronopik.de/vid.stab/)

Comment: I tried this on a 40MB 720p mp4 file from my Flip Mino HD camera. It did something: it spit out a file called `VID00055.MP4.trf`. What do I do with that?

Comment: ok, looks like that did something, but there's no output video file. In the console output I see `[transcode] warning: no option -o found, encoded frames send to "/dev/null"` and `[transcode] warning: no option -y found, option -o ignored, writing to "/dev/null"`. Do you know what those options should be? Sorry, never used transcode before, and I'm finding it a bit hard to use.

Comment: `transcode -J transform -i VID00055.MP4 -y raw,tcaud -o out.mp4` worked, but the resulting audio is horrible (choppy). Oh well.

Comment: Could you also package this up in a bash script? `transcode -J stabilize -i $1 -y null,null -o dummy` and then `transcode -J transform -i $1 -y xvid,null -o out-$1`. Then once you've found the right settings (that work for you), wrap this in a for loop.

Comment: "After installation of the plugin" how this can be done?

Comment: @reducingactivity: sorry for that - links changed a bit over the years. See edit for clarification

Comment: @Takkat `Package transcode is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'transcode' has no installation candidate` (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @reducingactivity: sorry again - you're entirely correct. Transcode was only available up to 18.04. It is removed from Ubuntu in newer releases as it was nbo longer maintainend and also had issues with ffmpeg. Unortunately I have no experience with any replacement.