# Deshaking videos using script

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcode

How can I deshake my video?

I try to use transcode:

```
transcode  -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i "input.MTS"
```

But it causes a segfault.

Trying to use ffmpeg filters:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.MTS" -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=5:show=1 out.avi
ffmpeg -i "input.MTS" -vf deshake out.avi
```

But always have an error "No such filter".

I want to create a simple nautilus script for this.

Comment: Transcode should not segfault, play with options. See may answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/228841/what-ubuntu-compatible-software-is-available-to-remove-shaking-from-a-video with links to tutorials.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Currently, `ffmpeg` from the repository only supports the simpler [deshake](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deshake) filter, but does not support the better [vidstab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vidstabdetect-1) filters.

You have a few options to get vidstab support: compile or use a PPA.

---

## Compiling

This is the best option if you also want to customize your `ffmpeg` or use the latest version.

First you will have to compile libvidstab or use the [libvidstab-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libvidstab-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package. Currently only 19.04 Disco Dingo and newer provides this package. Alternatively, 16.04 Xenial Xerus users can use the libvidstab-dev package from the [mc3man PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-test)).

To compile libvidstab:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
$ mkdir ~/ffmpeg_sources ~/ffmpeg_build
$ cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
$ wget -O https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip
$ cd vid.stab-master
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=~/ffmpeg_build .
$ make
$ make install
```

Now follow [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). When you get to the step where `ffmpeg` is configured then add `--enable-libvidstab` to the list of configure options.

---

## mc3man PPA

[FFmpeg current release plus git PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-test) for 16.04 Xenial Xerus:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/ffmpeg-test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg-static
```

Now run `ffmpeg2` **(note the "2").**

---

## Usage

See the [vid.stab usage instructions](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab#usage-instructions).

---

## Also see

- [deshake](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deshake), [vidstabdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vidstabdetect-1), and [vidstabtransform](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vidstabtransform-1) FFmpeg filter documentation.

Comment: `config` step of building ffmpeg fails for me with `ERROR: vidstab not found using pkg-config`. What am I missing ?

Comment: Also Doug's PPA doesn't have libvidstab-dev

Comment: @guettli It shouldn't. That was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer.

Comment: For all (like me), who read too fast: you need to use ffmpeg**2**

Comment: doesn't seem to work with ubuntu 17.04

Comment: @wotanii More detailed information is required to be able to determine the actual issue.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Because I was missing  'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/install_dir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' ffmpeg couldn't find libvidstab. I added it and now it works.

Comment: There's no ppa for 17.04 :-/

Answer (score 3):

As others mention above that Doug's PPA doesn't support **Zesty (17.04)** - as of 08/19/2017. As 17.10 will come out in October 16.04 solutions will be more and more obsolete. Two possible solutions for Zesty users:

1. Simpler: just use a static build https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
2. More work: install the `vid.stab` from github (https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab read the compile instructions, very simple), and then compile `ffmpeg` https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Since I don't have too much time, I like the first solution, worked flawlessly.

The vidstab first pass works on 1 core only, but since my GoPro footage is in many chunks, I could process 4 video simultaneously if I'd want 100% system load. The second pass utilizes all 4 cores.

My laptop i7-6820HK but both passes only progress with about 0.12x speed. So it's pretty slow, but I won't care if the result will be nice.

---

Update: my helmet mount footage seems to be so shaky that shakiness 10 is not enough. I don't know what to do, that's the max...

Comment: I tried the `deshake` for my helmet mounted GoPro bicycle footages but it looked like almost didn't do anything. Deshake is part of the official Ubuntu version of `ffmpeg`, maybe there's some parameter combination it'd work better, but reading on the net sounds like `vid.stab` will be better.

Comment: Yes, vidstab is better, but more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I guess many people (me included) found this question, trying just to use ffmpeg with the filter.

Those answers about compiling are great, but it's time-consuming and may be difficult for some people.

Nowadays there is a simple option to use Docker image that is already built with many filters, codecs and more.

Personally, I used this image https://github.com/jrottenberg/ffmpeg

Sample usage is very simple for deshake filter:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/temp/ \
    jrottenberg/ffmpeg \
    -i /temp/input.MTS \
    -vf deshake \
    /temp/out.avi
```

As well for vidstab filter:

```
# create vectors from input file
docker run -v $PWD:/temp/ jrottenberg/ffmpeg \
    -i /temp/input.MTS \
    -vf vidstabdetect=stepsize=6:shakiness=8:accuracy=9:result=/temp/transform_vectors.trf -f null -

# process file using vectors from step 1
docker run -v $PWD:/temp/ jrottenberg/ffmpeg \
    -i /temp/input.MTS \
    -vf vidstabtransform=input=/temp/transform_vectors.trf:zoom=1:smoothing=30,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 \
    /temp/out.avi
```

Just mind that created file "out.avi" will have `root` owner and that should be changed.